# Which assembly do I need for DispatcherTimer? namespace not working

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

I have an issue on a project using WPF. I am trying to use DispatchTimer. I see in another example the `using DispatcherTimer = Windows.UI.Xaml.DispatcherTimer;`  namespace.

This does not work for me. I assume I am missing some assembly but can't seem to find which it might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The namespace you are using is WinRT not WPF. For WPF use `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`, which is in assembly WindowsBase.dll, which is required to run WPF.

Comment: MSDN link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx